# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29 cannot be cast to com.frodo.questionbank.service.impl.QuestionService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring-Hibernate project. My main concern is related to how and where to open and close Hibernate session. I googled it and I found article related to spring transaction manager. I used this in my code. But I am getting some error related to typecasting of proxies.
I have multiple service and dao classes and I am using Interface Service which every service class implements.
In controller I am writing code like this

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="questionDisplayService")
    Service questionService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="questionService")
    Service qService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="userServiceImpl")
    Service uService;
```

And I am type casting later on like this

```
 long questionid = ((QuestionService) qService).addQuestionService(question, tagsid);
```

Now I am getting following error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy29 cannot be cast to com.frodo.questionbank.service.impl.QuestionService

Please suggest me the way or any better approach which I can use.

Comment: Horrible coding..!! Change service with respective service classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is terrible. A service is supposed to have a clear contract. This contract is defined by the interface of the service. All your services share the same interface, which doesn't make any sense: why would two completely different services share the same contract and have the same methods?

Since they obviously don't have the same methods, now you're forced to cast to a concrete class instead of relying on their interface, and you thus lose type-safety (and testability) completely. And since they all have the same interface, you're also forced to use a qualifier to distinguish them.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    QuestionDisplayService questionDisplayService;

    @Autowired
    QuestionService questionService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    ...

    long questionid = questionService.addQuestionService(question, tagsid);
```

Comment: thanks @Nizet.I updated code as u suggested.now i m getting new error-No bean named 'txMgr' is defined.

Comment: I found an article  [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-nosuchbeandefinitionexception) and tried that as well.but it not worked

Comment: That is a completely different problem, unrelated to the problem in this question. Ask another question, showing the relevant code, config files, and the exception stack trace.